# Qt app built with CMake compiles, but doesn't run, in Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, qt5

I'm porting a program to Windows and I got it to compile, but when I run it, it says " Qt5Cored.dll: cannot open shared object file".

I'm setting up a Windows box to port programs I've written on Linux to Windows. All of my C++ programs use CMake. After setting up Git, ssh, CMake, and MinGW, I compiled a program that uses no libraries except C++ and math and got it to run. I then installed Qt and cloned Mirasol (https://github.com/phma/mirasol ; it's for teaching young children numbers) and got it to compile, but it doesn't run.

This is my build script on Windows. Suggestions on where to install programs are welcome. CMake did not find Qt until I told it where to look.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/c/Qt/5.13.0/lib/cmake/Qt5
export Qt5_DIR="C:/Qt/5.13.0/mingw73_64/lib/cmake/Qt5"
mkdir -p ~/build/$1
cd ~/build/$1
mkdir -p dbg
mkdir -p rel
mkdir -p ins
cd dbg
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~ ~/src/$1
cd ../rel
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~ ~/src/$1
cd ../ins
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ~/src/$1
```

My build script on Linux is at http://bezitopo.org/developers.html (I've since added afl and Android builds, which are irrelevant).

On Linux, it runs fine, and "ldd mirasol" produces the following output:

```
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdfe6d1000)
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f714c35d000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f714bbf4000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f714b4a9000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f714b120000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f714ad82000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f714ab6a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f714a779000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f714a55a000)
        libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f714a2ce000)
        libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f714a09c000)
        libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f7149dfe000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7149be1000)
        libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007f7149740000)
        libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f7149389000)
        libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x00007f7149178000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7148f74000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7148c5e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f714cdf9000)
        libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f7148a2d000)
        libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f7148777000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f71484c3000)
        libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f7148296000)
        libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f71466ed000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f714647b000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f7146143000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f7145f1b000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f7145d17000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f7145b11000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f71458fc000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f71456f4000)
```

On Windows, running it produces the error

```
 C:/Users/phma/build/mirasol/dbg/mirasol.exe: error while loading shared libraries: Qt5Widgetsd.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and ldd produces the output

```
        ntdll.dll => /c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffad3a20000)
        KERNEL32.DLL => /c/Windows/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffad3010000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /c/Windows/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffad0e10000)
        msvcrt.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffad3560000)
        libgcc_s_seh-1.dll => /mingw64/bin/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (0x61440000)
        libstdc++-6.dll => /mingw64/bin/libstdc++-6.dll (0x6fc40000)
        USER32.dll => /c/Windows/System32/USER32.dll (0x7ffad2bb0000)
        win32u.dll => /c/Windows/System32/win32u.dll (0x7ffad0c30000)
        GDI32.dll => /c/Windows/System32/GDI32.dll (0x7ffad2e00000)
        gdi32full.dll => /c/Windows/System32/gdi32full.dll (0x7ffad1840000)
        msvcp_win.dll => /c/Windows/System32/msvcp_win.dll (0x7ffad0a60000)
        ucrtbase.dll => /c/Windows/System32/ucrtbase.dll (0x7ffad0b30000)
```

. It doesn't say "Qt5Widgetsd.dll => not found", and I don't know where the extra 'd' came from.

ETA: I changed the build script to tell CMake to use MSYS Makefiles instead of Ninja. I still get the error.

ETA: I copied the DLLs to the directory where the program is compiled, and it runs. It doesn't look canonical to me, coming from Linux where the libraries are in /usr/lib/, but on Windows, in the bin directory next to the Kate binary, are many DLLs.

Comment: the d suffixed names are the debug versions.see also here [Application Dependencies](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#application-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put the debug versions of the dlls (look at the *d* postfix of the output) near the EXE (remember that Windows adds "./" to the cwd.

The *d* postfix is because you built a debug version.